# "Vendor image does not match the system" message at boot

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5x

I flashed Pure Nexus on my Nexus 5X and I'm enjoying it. But every time I boot my phone I get the following message:

[image]

**Is it possible to get rid of this message?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Do as the hint says: grab the corresponding factory image (in your case MTC20F) [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en), extract `vendor.img` from it (you might need 7-Zip), then flash it in fastboot mode via `fastboot flash vendor PATH_TO_VENDOR_IMG`. Reboot and you should be fine.

Be sure to also update the bootloader (`fastboot flash bootloader PATH_TO_BOOTLOADER_IMG`) and baseband (`fastboot flash radio PATH_TO_RADIO_IMG`) too. This should be made a routine as you update your ROM afterwards.

Comment: But I have Pure Nexus, doesn't flashing the vendor image go back to pretty much "factory settings"?

Comment: @TeunissenStefan No, you might be thinking about "factory image" which this is _a part of_, and thus will not touch your data.

Comment: @AndyYan your instructions are flawless, thank you so much.